# Wireless and bluetooth suddenly stopped working

Tags: wifi, bluetooth, pi-zero-w

My raspberry pi zero w was lying useless since a year because the wireless and bluetooth interfaces were not showing up.I thought it was a hardware problem but this year after the April release of raspbian stretch,I gave another try and by God's grace everything was working but now suddenly everything stopped.The old problem began again.I even tried by reinstalling the raspbian but still the wireless and bluetooth is not working.The zero w cannot detect any bluetooth or wireless interface.When trying `rfkill list all` command there is no output.Can someone tell me what's the problem I don't think it's a hardware related issue because otherwise it would not start working suddenly after a year,I thought it was some os issue which got solved after the April release but now I cannot make out anything.Can someone please help me with this.Please ask me for further details which are required for solving the problem.The `ifconfig` also gives only lists `lo` and `usb` when runned using headless setup and only `lo` when used hdmi(The normal setup).

Comment: a heat related issue would present itself in the way that you describe .... try cooling off the board with canned air duster while it is plugged in .... or unplug it and stick it in a freezer for a while .... see if that brings the interfaces back to life

Comment: Are you sure the freezer won't damage it